# get current date in stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in mysql

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc ()
    BEGIN

     SELECT YEAR(dtm), 
            WEEK(dtm), 
            b.x_title, 
            COUNT(b.x_id)  
       INTO OUTFILE '/appdata/reports01/result.csv'  
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'    
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
       FROM tbla a 
       JOIN tblb b ON b.x_id = a.x_id 
      WHERE plan_grp_id IN (10031, 10034) 
        AND dtm > '20110101' 
   GROUP BY YEAR(dtm), WEEK(dtm), a.x_id;

  END //


delimiter ;
```

I need to do two things

1. `INTO OUTFILE '/appdata/reports01/result.csv'` must be like "INTO OUTFILE '/appdata/reports01/result-**current-timestamp**.csv'
2. dtm > '20110101' must be dtm > CURDATE() + 0 .

This:

```
SELECT  CURDATE() + 0
```

...gets me the format '20110101', but I can't use that in the query like `dtm > CURDATE() + 0`

Comment: Not sure about the file name. As for the second 'thing', what type is `dtm`? Did you try simply `dtm > CURDATE()`?

Comment: yeah.. I tried but it dosent work for some reason. I found a work around for this.. dtm > (SELECT CURDATE() + 0 ). but cant get the filename timestamp..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variables.

```
DECLARE outfile_name varchar(300);
```

Get the current timestamp and append it to the remaining part of the string.
Use INTO keyword to get the output of the SELECT statement into a variable.
Use CONCAT() for concatinating 2 strings.